# Can I create a date object out of this type of string? in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

Hello I have a XML file and a "created at" tag that stores the date and time like this
2012-09-15 02:08:46
I am trying to create a new Date object so I can easily print out the day month and year. But it doesn't like this format.

something like this

```
var theDate = new Date(Date.parse(storyDate));

console.log(theDate.getMonth());
theDate = theDate.getDate() + ", " + theDate.getMonth();
```

thanks

UPDATE: I can get it to work in Chrome but not Firefox. 
UPDATE: Found the answer, thanks everybody. why the downvote? It turned out to be a reasonable question. I was missing a T.

Comment: should I just use regular expressions? I'm not very good at that yet.

Comment: What's the problem you're having? I tried the code and it works

Comment: really? I'm typing it straight into firebug and its saying NaN

Comment: >>> var theDate = new Date(Date.parse('2012-09-15 02:08:46')); 

undefined

>>> theDate.getMonth();

NaN

Comment: @FunBeans: exactly this code worksforme, yielding `1347667726000` (for parse) and `8` (for getMonth)

Comment: @timidboy: OK, it was Opera :-) FF seems to need a `T` between date and time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var theDate = new Date(Date.parse(storyDate.replace(' ', 'T')));
```

The 'T' is required between the date and time.(at least in FireFox)

[Valid DateTime formats](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)

Comment: seems strange there would be a difference in this way between ff and chrome

Answer (score 1):

I would parse the date manually using regular expressions.

```
var dateStr = "2012-09-15 02:08:46"
var dateRegex = /^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})\s(\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/
var dateParts = dateRegex.exec(dateStr)
var year = dateParts[1], 
    month = parseInt(dateParts[2], 10) - 1,
    day = dateParts[3],
    hour = dateParts[4],
    minutes = dateParts[5],
    seconds = dateParts[6];
var date = new Date(year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds);
//
console.log(date.getMonth())
console.log(date.getDate() + ", " + date.getMonth());
```

Comment: thanks! I saved this. I think I'm gonna use the other thing, but I filed this under js regex's i might use.